# SQL checking if value is between period

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

I am trying to check if the date is between start_date and end_date, but this won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_foo
WHERE start_date BEFORE '2015-02-21T00:00:00' AND 
      end_date AFTER '2015-02-21T00:00:00';
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Can I use NOW() instead of '2015-02-21T00:00:00'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost...

```
SELECT * FROM table_foo
WHERE start_date < TIMESTAMP '2015-02-21 00:00:00.0' AND 
      end_date > TIMESTAMP '2015-02-21 00:00:00.0';
```

This makes use of the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP` literal syntax, which consists of the keyword `TIMESTAMP` and an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date time representation (without the `T`!). You can then easily use `<` and `>` to compare timestamps.

From your comments, if you want to use the current time, write:

```
SELECT * FROM table_foo
WHERE start_date < SYSTIMESTAMP AND 
      end_date > SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

Or even:

```
SELECT * FROM table_foo
WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a rockstar! Is there any possibility of using NOW() instead of '2015-02-21 00:00:00.0' ?

Comment: It is called `SYSTIMESTAMP` in Oracle